# Web service handler doesn't work when a service calls another service

Tags: web-services, soap, handler

I'm testing out web service handlers, and I've created two mock services and a mock client. The client (A) calls the service (B) which calls the other service (C). I have one handler on B and another on C, both just print that they have been activated. What I would expect is for the B handler to activate 4 times (once when A contacts him, once when he contacts C, once when C replies and once when B should reply to A), but he only activates when A contacts him and when he has to reply to A. The handler on C work as expected (is activated twice).

I have the following code that starts the services and activates the client:

```
    Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/WSSecurity/helloworld", new WSDocEndpointImpl());
    Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8081/WSSecurity2/helloworld2", new WSDocEndpointImpl2());

    URL wsdlUrl = new URL("http://localhost:8081/WSSecurity2/helloworld2?wsdl");
    QName qname = new QName("http://webservice2.document.ftn.uns.ac.rs/", "WSDocEndpointImpl2Service");
    Service service = Service.create(wsdlUrl, qname);
    WSDocEndpoint2 helloWS = service.getPort(WSDocEndpoint2.class);
    String response = helloWS.getHelloWorldAsString("Petar");
    System.out.println(response);
```

My web services:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "rs.ac.uns.ftn.document.webservice.WSDocEndpoint")
@HandlerChain(file = "/rs/ac/uns/ftn/document/handler-chain-document.xml")
public class WSDocEndpointImpl implements WSDocEndpoint {

@Override
public String getHelloWorldAsString(String name) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("ARRIVED AT WS 1 --- " + new Date());
    return "Hello, " + name;
}
}

@WebService(endpointInterface = "rs.ac.uns.ftn.document.webservice2.WSDocEndpoint2")
@HandlerChain(file = "/rs/ac/uns/ftn/document/handler-chain-document2.xml")
public class WSDocEndpointImpl2 implements WSDocEndpoint2 {

@Override
public String getHelloWorldAsString(String name) {
    try {
        URL wsdlUrl = new URL(
                "http://localhost:8080/WSSecurity/helloworld?wsdl");
        QName qname = new QName(
                "http://webservice.document.ftn.uns.ac.rs/",
                "WSDocEndpointImplService");
        Service service = Service.create(wsdlUrl, qname);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("ARRIVED AT WS 2 --- " + new Date());
        WSDocEndpoint helloWS = service.getPort(WSDocEndpoint.class);
        String responseFromWS1 = helloWS.getHelloWorldAsString("Petar");
        return responseFromWS1;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "EXCEPTION!";
    }
}
}
```

The handle message methods:

```
@Override
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.err.println("TEST HANDLER! --- " + new Date());

    return true;
}
```

And finally the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<hc:handler-chains xmlns:hc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <hc:handler-chain>
        <hc:handler>
            <hc:handler-class>rs.ac.uns.ftn.document.handler.TestHandler</hc:handler-class>
        </hc:handler>
    </hc:handler-chain>
</hc:handler-chains>
```

The output I get on the console:

```
TEST HANDLER 2! --- Fri May 15 18:58:35 CEST 2015
ARRIVED AT WS 2 --- Fri May 15 18:58:36 CEST 2015
TEST HANDLER! --- Fri May 15 18:58:38 CEST 2015
ARRIVED AT WS 1 --- Fri May 15 18:58:39 CEST 2015
TEST HANDLER! --- Fri May 15 18:58:41 CEST 2015
TEST HANDLER 2! --- Fri May 15 18:58:43 CEST 2015
Hello, Petar
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the way I wrote my code. When my web service acted as a client it wasn't processing the handler. I had to generate a web service client for my web service and register the handler on him, and then use him to call my other web service.